# WordPress.com: Domain Mapping a current site

Tags: domains, wordpress

I currently have a site hosted by a different company and I wanted to domain map the WordPress.com site to the host provider eventually.

However, I still have yet to make a WordPress.com site and I want to keep my current site up while working on the WordPress.com site as I don’t want the current site to be down while my clients are still going to the original site.

Would I be able to work on a temporary WordPress.com site and eventually add a domain (domain mapping) later and move all my work to the new WordPress.com site? Or will I have to domain map the WordPress.com site first and then start working on it from scratch? If I can move all my work from the temporary WordPress.com site to the new WordPress.com site how would I go about doing it?

Also, does anyone have any recommendations on how to keep my current site up while working on the new site in WordPress?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best (only?) way to do this is using a subdomain e.g. `new.example.com`. In WordPress create your account using the subdomain.  Find the A Record for this new site, here's how: https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/custom-dns/#viewing-your-dns-records

In your current hosting create the subdomain `new.example.com` and change the DNS to point the A Record to the IP address you found above.  Once it resolves you can then start working on your new site.

Then once your new site is finished you would change your WordPress.com site from the subdomain to `example.com` and update the A Record to the same IP address.

That technique works generally, but I don't know if you can change the domain at WordPress.com.